# jqtree click event not working on partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqtree

I am using jqtree for filtering products through categories. It works during the first time I click a category. 
After selecting a category, I'll click the search button to display the Items data which is in partial view.
Then when I will select another category to search for another set of data, The click event does not work anymore.

jquery code I used:

```
function SearchProducts() {
    var dataToSave = ko.toJSON({
        productname: $('#txtProductName').val(),
        categoryId: $('#lblCategoryID').text()
    });

    var url = '@Url.Action("AddEditProduct", "Inventory")';
        $.ajax(url, {
            data: dataToSave,
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#addeditproduct").html(result);
            }
        });
    };

    $(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetCategoryTreeView","Inventory")'
    $('#SelectedCategoryID').text();

    $('#tree1').tree({
        dataUrl: url,
        autoOpen: 1,
        selectable: true
    });
});

$('#tree1').bind(
    'tree.click',
    function (event) {
        var node = event.node;
        SelectedCategory = '';
        lblParentID = '';
        lblParentName = '';
        $('#SelectedCategoryID').text('');
        lblParentID = node.ID;
        lblParentName = node.name;
        SelectedCategory = 'Category Selected: ' + node.name + ' (Category ID: ' + lblParentID + ')';
        $('#SelectedCategoryID').text(SelectedCategory);
        $('#lblCategory').text(node.name + ' (' + lblParentID + ')');
        lblCatID = lblParentID;
        $('#lblCategoryID').text(lblParentID)
    }
);
```

Code at controller for searching products

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEditProduct(VMAddEditProduct viewModel)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.Username == this.User.Identity.Name).Single();
        dynamic items = null;
        if (viewModel.CategoryId != 0)
        {
            if (viewModel.ProductName != null && viewModel.ProductName != "")
            {
                items = (from product in db.tblFMSItems
                         join category in db.FMSCategory on product.CategoryID equals category.ID
                         where product.CenterID == user.CenterId
                         && product.CategoryID == viewModel.CategoryId
                         && product.ProductName == viewModel.ProductName
                         select new
                         {
                             CategoryId = product.CategoryID,
                             ProductId = product.ProductId,
                             ProductName = product.ProductName,
                             CategoryName = category.ProductType,
                             SKU = product.SKU,
                             Desc = product.Desc
                         })
                        .OrderBy(product => product.ProductName)
                        .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                items = (from product in db.tblFMSItems
                         join category in db.FMSCategory on product.CategoryID equals category.ID
                         where product.CenterID == user.CenterId
                         && product.CategoryID == viewModel.CategoryId
                         select new
                         {
                             CategoryId = product.CategoryID,
                             ProductId = product.ProductId,
                             ProductName = product.ProductName,
                             CategoryName = category.ProductType,
                             SKU = product.SKU,
                             Desc = product.Desc
                         })
                            .OrderBy(product => product.ProductName)
                            .ToList();
            }
        }
        else if (viewModel.ProductName != null && viewModel.ProductName != "")
        {
            items = (from product in db.tblFMSItems
                     join category in db.FMSCategory on product.CategoryID equals category.ID
                     where product.CenterID == user.CenterId
                     && product.ProductName == viewModel.ProductName
                     select new
                     {
                         CategoryId = product.CategoryID,
                         ProductId = product.ProductId,
                         ProductName = product.ProductName,
                         CategoryName = category.ProductType,
                         SKU = product.SKU,
                         Desc = product.Desc
                     })
                    .OrderBy(product => product.ProductName)
                    .ToList();
        }
        else if ((viewModel.ProductName == null) && viewModel.CategoryId == 0)
        {
            items = (from product in db.tblFMSItems
                     join category in db.FMSCategory on product.CategoryID equals category.ID
                     where product.CenterID == user.CenterId
                     select new
                     {
                         CategoryId = product.CategoryID,
                         ProductId = product.ProductId,
                         ProductName = product.ProductName,
                         CategoryName = category.ProductType,
                         SKU = product.SKU,
                         Desc = product.Desc
                     })
                    .OrderBy(product => product.ProductName)
                    .ToList();
        }
        var results = new List<VMAddEditProduct>();



        foreach (var fmsitem in items)
        {
            var itemDesc = "";
            if (fmsitem.Desc != null && fmsitem.Desc.Contains("<br/>"))
            {
                itemDesc = fmsitem.Desc.Replace("<br/>", "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                itemDesc = fmsitem.Desc;
            }
            var result = new VMAddEditProduct();
            result.CategoryId = fmsitem.CategoryId;
            result.CategoryName = fmsitem.CategoryName;
            result.ProductId = fmsitem.ProductId;
            result.SKU = fmsitem.SKU;
            result.ProductName = fmsitem.ProductName;
            result.Desc = itemDesc;

            results.Add(result);
        }
        return View("~/Views/Report/AddEditProducts.cshtml", results);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error here:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqtree.css")" />
```

The "src" causes the jqtree.css not to be used by my page, so I changed it to "href" which fixed the issue.